# If my UIView is set be opaque, why is it still being colored as "blended" by the simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that at initialization I set to be opaque (`opaque = YES`), and if I use the "Debug View Hierarchy" button to preview the views at runtime, I can see that it is indeed set to be opaque as I would expect.

However if I turn on Color Blended Layers in the iOS Simulator, that same view is red, indicated it is blended, which for performance reasons I don't want.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? Why is it still blended?

Comment: Did you set the label's `backgroundColor` to an opaque color?

Comment: @robmayoff Sigh. That would do it. Assumed opaqueness would automatically handle that in some fashion, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A view is not opaque (even if you set `opaque = YES`) for compositing unless it has an opaque `backgroundColor`.